# Magento2: How to configure CodeSniffer in phpstorm?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I want to configure code sniffer in phpstorm so i can refactor my code according to Magento coding standards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code Sniffer Configurations:**

> Open PHPStorm, Alt + Ctrl + S Select PHP > Quality Tools >
> PHP_Codesniffer > ... > Give the path of
> "Suizlabs/PHP_Codesniffer/bin/phpcs" Then validate it and apply/Ok
>
> Select Editor > Inspections > PHP > Quality Tools > Check the
> PHP_CodeSniffer validation Then in OPTIONS on the right side check all
> the options Give path of
> "vendor/magento/magento-coding-standard/Magento2" to Installed
> standards path
>
> After that select "magento2" from the coding standard dropdown and
> apply/Ok.

**Steps to properly configure spacing or lint feature in PHPStorm:**

> ctrl + alt + s Editor --> Code Style --> PHP --> Set from -->
> PSR1/PSR2 Apply and OK Press CTRL + ALT + L or CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + L

Comment: well answered. Thanks @P.A

Comment: This one magically solved my problem. Thank you so much!